# Changing CSS when input have some value inside

Tags: html, jquery, css

I managed to do that copy of elements:
[image]

The only problem is that I did this on click event and I want the class to trigger only when the input have some value, another problem is that it changes all the input, I want to change only the input that I'm currently on it.

I have the in jquery:

```
$(':input[type=text],:input[type=email]').click(function () {
 $('.tbi-label').toggleClass('tbi-visible-label');
});
```

The html:

```
<div class="tbi-content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 tbi-input">
          <div class="tbi-label text-grey-50" data-label-for="applicantDataId_PIN">Your CNP</div>
          <div class="tbi-container">{applicantDataId_PIN}</div>
          <div class="tbi-tooltip">We need it to verify your identity</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 tbi-input">
          <div class="tbi-label text-grey-50" data-label-for="applicantDataId_phone">Your phone number</div>
          <div class="tbi-container">{applicantDataId_phone}</div>
          <div class="tbi-tooltip">We will inform you abour Ioan status</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

How can I solve my problem? I tried using this but is not working:

```
 $(':input[type=text],:input[type=email]').on('input change',function () {
   if($(this).val() !== ''){
   $('.tbi-label').toggleClass('tbi-visible-label');
   }
 });
```

Comment: Using 'this' is a good start. However you have to find the correct label. One solution is to use closest. Documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: Try to use on `change` event
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

Comment: Why don't you have any actual inputs? This looks like an accessibility fail.

Comment: They are inputs inside, I'm using a platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know where you input is. But if you place your input and that label in common parent class then this code will work.

```js
 $(':input[type=text],:input[type=email]').on('input change',function () {
   if($(this).val() !== ''){
     $(this).closest('.tbi-input').find('.tbi-label').removeClass('d-none');
   }else{
         $(this).closest('.tbi-input').find('.tbi-label').addClass('d-none');
   }
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Stack overflow</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form class="p-2">
  <div class="form-group tbi-input">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small  class="tbi-label form-text text-muted d-none">something about email.</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group tbi-input">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
     <small class="tbi-label form-text text-muted d-none">somthiong about password.</small>
  </div>
  
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```